# Copy Paste a variable range with variable row number i to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, integer, range, long-integer

The following code is working in my mind but not in vba:

```
Dim i As Integer

If Range("H11") = i Then Range("U" & i & ":X" & i).Select

Selection.Copy

lrij = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A" & lrij + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Range("H11").ClearContents

Range("A1").Activate
```

i is a variable row number.
The purpose is if I enter "2" for example in Cell "H11", the Range ("U2:X2") will be copy pasted in Column "A", row under row.

braX already helped me with writing the variable range correctly, but I'm lacking the point here I guess. He advised me to use the "Long" data type.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you want `Dim i As Long`, `i = Range("H11").Value`.

Comment: Wow it works, thank you very much. Can you help me understand what exactly makes this work and not what I did? Thank you

Comment: If you declare `i` as Long, it will by default start with a value of zero (see https://bettersolutions.com/vba/variables/initialising.htm), so your posted code checks to see if the value of H11 is zero before selecting a range.

Comment: Tim Williams thank you for explaining!